# Can't get a value from an HTML element

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

```
<div id="a_1" class="c_1">
   <h3><img src="image.png" alt="image text" />versions</h3>
   <div>
      <dl>
         <dt>V1</dt>
            <dd>14</dd>
         <dt>V2</dt>
            <dd>5776</dd>
      </dl>
   </div>
</div>
```

How can I get 14?  I tried something like this:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c_1']//a[@href]");
```

Comment: lets see some of what you've tried huh.

Comment: I tried this document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("div/div/dl/dt/dd[1]")

Comment: According to the above, `<dd>` is **not** a child of `<dt>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c_1']//dd[1]");
```

OR

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@class='c_1']/div/dl/dd[1]");
```